# Batch Processing of files from a directory in openSmile toolkit

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, batch-processing, feature-extraction

I am trying to read speech files (.wav) from a directory one by one and extract the feature and store it filewise. I am unable to do so.

Any help will be appreciated.

I am new to Linux and OpenSmile.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post what error messages you are getting, along with some code snippets that you tried

Answer (score 0):

OK so am too late for this.

But I have just coded a solution for my specific case, I'll request you to do the necessary changes.

Rather than Uploading here, I'll request you to check my [GitHub](https://github.com/vybhav72954/Capstone_EEG/blob/master/Features/6373_Fetures.py) Repo, as the code is over 300 lines long, and requires some changes and updates.

Comment: when I edit the code in the repo (GitHub) I have this error `CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/asus/Desktop/opensmile-3.0.0/SMILExtract', '-C', 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/opensmile-3.0.0/config/IS10_paraling_compat.conf', '-I', 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/opensmile-3.0.0/example-audio/RAVDESS/Audio_Speech_Actors_01-24/Actor_01/03-01-01-01-01-01-01.wav', '-O', 'C:/Users/asus/Desktop/IS10features_lld/03-01-01-01-01-01-01.csv']' returned non-zero exit status 4294967295.`  please, any help will be appreciated.